# Input File on Android WebView

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview

is there any way to simply open the Default File Explorer to choose a file if someone clicks on an 
    input[type=file]
 in a WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no "default file explorer" in Android, you are at the mercy of whatever the implementer of the browser did. In the case of `WebView`, I am not certain what it will do by default, perhaps nothing.

I am no DOM/JS expert, but I would think that you could modify things such that an `onClick` event on the `<input type="file">` would call into Java code that you inject via `addJavascriptInterface()`, at which point you can bring up whatever sort of "file explorer" you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. I'd love to see a dialog that takes advantage of the PhoneGap File API's that would allow you to graphically select a file but no one has done it to my knowledge.